# mongodb configuration file parameters

Tags: mongodb

I don't understand the oplogging level parameter, I have created a replicaset with two members and one arbiter. the two members are synchronised with oplog.
Why the default oplogging parameter is 0, means it is off? I though this parameter was 3 (Read + Write) by default

```
# Set oplogging level where n is
#   0=off (default)
#   1=W
#   2=R
#   3=both
#   7=W+some reads
```

thanks for your help

Fabrice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setting you are talking about is not for oplogs. This configuration is for diagnostic logs. The value mentioned is for setting `diaglog` parameter. The config file section for this looks like -

```
# Set oplogging level where n is
#   0=off (default)
#   1=W
#   2=R
#   3=both
#   7=W+some reads
#diaglog = 0
```

Yes, debugging is off by default.

Comment: I understand now, thaks very much